# How to find all primitive triples (a,b,c)? (Pythagorean Triples)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

how to find all primitive triples when one value of $(a,b,c)$ is given? For example in this case $a = 45$.

What is the procedure to find the primitive triples ?

Conditions for primitive triples are:

1. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
2. $(a,b) = 1$
3. $a$ and $c$ are odd and $b$ is even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a well-known parametrization of primitive triples as $(n^2-m^2, 2mn, n^2+m^2)$ for appropriate values of $n,m$.  So for your problem you should proceed by solving for $n$ and $m$ coprime such that $n^2-m^2  = (n+m)(n-m) = 45$.

Comment: so i guess the values of n and m by trail and error?

Comment: You can determine what $n+m$ and $n-m$ are by considering all possible factorizations of $45$.

Comment: so I did prime factorisation of 45 = 3,3,5.
so possible pairs to be (m-n) (m+n) are : 9*5 or 3*15 or 45*1.
right?

Comment: those are the factorizations, but note that 3, 15 are both divisible by 3 so they don't give a primitive triple

Comment: yes i got the point i mean i split factors in 2 parts and get the actual (n+m) = 9 and (n-m)=5 and find m and n from here on and then test it into (n2−m2,2mn,n2+m2) weather it forms a triples or not.
But after all this final questions remains how I can be sure i found all the triples. And also what if the number given is very large (for example a = 1365 as there will be too many factors of this large number.

Comment: Since all primitive triples are of the given form, you can be sure that you have found them all.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be asking: "How do I find all primitive triples with a leg equal to a given number, say 45?".

A simple method is to use the "Fibonacci Box" shown below where $q',q$ are positive coprime integers with $q'$ odd, and where $q'+q=p$ and $q+p=p'$.

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    q  & q'  \\
    p  & p'
\end{array}} \right]$$

Then:

Inradius $r=q'q$ (First row product).

Odd leg $a=q'p'$ (Right column product).

Even leg $b=2qp$ (Left column product times two).

Hypotenuse $c= pp'-qq'$ (Difference of bottom row product and top row product).

For a triple with leg equal to 45, we find the factor pairs $q',p'$ that meet the conditions.  These are $q',p'=1,45$ and  $q',p'=5,9$.

So only 2 primitive triples with odd leg equal to 45 exist.

$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    2  & 5 \\
    7  & 9
\end{array}} \right]$ yields triple $(45, 28, 53)$.

$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    22  & 1 \\
    23  & 45
\end{array}} \right]$ yields triple $(45, 1012, 1013)$

Answer (score 0):

Well, think about the simplest pythagorean triple. It is $(3,4,5)$. So if you are given that $a=45$, divide $45$ by $3$ since $45$ is $a$ in your example and $3$ is a in a $(3,4,5)$ triangle. $45/3=15$. Ok, so now that you have done that, take the other sides in a $(3,4,5)$ triangle and multiply them by $15$. $4\cdot 15=60$ and $5\cdot15=75$. So that means that in your example, $a=45$, $b=60$, and $c=75$. Hope this helps. I at least think this is what you are asking about but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 0):

We can find Pythagorean triples for a given side $A$ by solving Euclid's formula for $n$ and then testing a finite number of $m$-values to see which generates an integer for $n$.

$$A=m^2-n^2\Rightarrow n=\sqrt{m^2-A}\qquad\qquad  \lceil\sqrt{A+1}\rceil \le m \le \biggl\lceil\frac{A}{2}\biggr\rceil$$
The lower limit ensures $m^2>A$ and the upper limit ensures $m-n\ge 1$.

In this case, we have $n=\sqrt{m^2-45}\quad \text{where}\quad \lceil\sqrt{46}\space\rceil=7\le m \le \lceil 22.5\rceil=23$

Texting, we find $3$ values of $m$ in this range that yield integers for $n$.

$\sqrt{7^2-45}=4,\quad F(7,4)=(33,56,65)\qquad GCD(33,56,65)=1$

$\sqrt{9^2-45}=6, \quad F(9,6)=(45,108,117)\qquad GCD(45,108,117)=9$

$\sqrt{23^2-45}=22, \quad F(23,22)=(45,1012,1013)\qquad GCD(45,1012,1013)=1$

We can see that $1$ of the triangles found not primitive. No other values of $m$ yield an integer so no other primitive triples exist where side $A=45$.